# Scons "Dir" command doesn't work?

Tags: variables, directory, command, scons, expansion

I've got a sub directory called "myc" containing 2 ".c" files:

```
$ ls myc
1.c  f.c
```

And my current directory has a SConstruct:

```
$ cat SConstruct 
myc=Dir('myc')
print myc
Program('test2',myc)
```

Run scons, it prints a bunch of errors:

```
$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
myc
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o test2 myc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find myc: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: *** [test2] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

What is weird: I expect the "print myc" will list "1.c" and "f.c", to my disappointment it prints "myc", not the varible value, and the compiling also fails.

How to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you believe that specifying a directory as the source(s) for a directory would work?

Is there something in the docs which makes you believe this should work?

If so, please point it out so it can be improved.

If you did:

gcc -o blah some_dir_name

That wouldn't work right?

This should do what you're asking for.

```
myc=Glob('myc/*.c')
print myc
Program('test2',myc)
```